# Angular2 Named router not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

https://plnkr.co/edit/x97F91xLv3yNcOhvTwBm?p=preview

in the plunker above currently clicking on Page1 or Page2 in the menu is loading the content into unnamed Router Outlet.
How do i load them into named router outlet(contentOutlet)?

i tried adding the following but it breaks the page

in app.module.ts

```
{ path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component, outlet:'contentOutlet'},

{ path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component, outlet:'contentOutlet'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of this code

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'Page1', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component, outlet="contentOutlet"},
{ path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component, outlet="contentOutlet"}`
```

is that you cannot load e.g. Page1 into an named outlet because you have to load exactly one component into the unnamed `router-outlet`. This outlet must not be empty. If you redirect the root path `''` directly to the component that you want to load into another outlet there's no component for the unnamed `router-outlet` available.

So you should create a parent component for the `Pages` which is always loaded into the unnamed `router-outlet` like this:

```
{ path: '', component: PagesComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'},
{ path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component, outlet: 'contentOutlet'}
```

Your outlets stay in the `AppComponent`.

If you want to load the `Page1` into the `contentOutlet` you should do it like this from the template of the `AppComponent`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {'contentOutlet': 'Page1' }}]" routerLinkActive="active" >Page1</a>
```

So now the router recognizes that there must be an outlet at the `/`-root Path of your application which is named `contentOutlet`. And he loads the `Page1`-Component into the outlet.

Here's the corrected plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MXi8p7rr15Bul1US9qbc?p=preview

Comment: Its is Quite confusing, do you recommend some tutorial or link to read upon this ?

I have update the plunker to load the Menus in the Left column. Now when i click the Page1child1 Menu i want to display the content of that page in the content Page, what do i need to do additional here.

Kind of want the navigation as on sears.com. 
1) Click on Menu in the header and it refreshes sub menu on the left
2) click on the submenu in the left and it will load the Contents to right side

Comment: This [article](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/) can be very helpful to get into the named router-outlets.

Comment: Thanks for helping out here. I'm a little confused. It seems the gist of your solution is to add the `'/'`, i.e. change `{outlets: {'contentOutlet': 'Page2' }}` to `'/', {outlets: {'contentOutlet': 'Page2' }}`. However, I opened your plunk and it works both ways. I am studying [this demo](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) in which a route fills only the named "popup" outlet. It works in the demo but not in [my adoption of it](https://great-big-angular2-example.herokuapp.com/heroes/crisis-center) into a larger app.